# Creating a table with a foreign key

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, create-table

Hey all I'm trying to create a table that contains a `Foreign Key`, and for some reason I am getting an error.  The error says `00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"` which is odd because I don't have a random left parenthesis.  I looked up how to create a table with a `Foreign Key` and that led to the following code:

```
Create Table EMPHIREINFO
(
empname VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES EMPADDRESS(empname),
empno NUMBER(4,0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
startdt DATE,
enddt DATE,
cntrlgth NUMBER(5,0)
)
```

I tried it with and without the `REFERENCES EMPADDRESS(empname)` and I still get the same error.  Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Witch DBMS are you using ?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning, but yes it is in Oracle.

Comment: Remove the words "FOREIGN KEY".  When specified as part of the column definition "REFERENCES EMPADDRESS(empname)" is all that's needed.  In fact, "REFERENCES EMPADDRESS" should be sufficient (assuming one and only one PRIMARY / UNIQUE key on EMPADDRESS).

Comment: @LarryLustig Okay, thank you for taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify column after `FOREIGN KEY`. However, I'd prefer to use naming constraints, for instance

```
Create Table EMPHIREINFO
(
empname VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL ,
empno NUMBER(4,0) NOT NULL ,
startdt DATE,
enddt DATE,
cntrlgth NUMBER(5,0),
CONSTRAINT PK_EMPHIREINFO PRIMARY KEY(empno) USING INDEX
 (CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IDXU_EMPHIREINFO_empno ON EMPHIREINFO(empno) ),
 CONSTRAINT FK_EMPHIREINFO_EMPNAME FOREIGN KEY(empname)
 REFERENCES EMPADDRESS(empname)
)
```

Comment: +1 for naming the constraints (although the "using index" is a bit of an overkill and probably confuses a newbie like Adam)

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for clearing that up.  From what I took away from your post it looks like I was missing the keyword `CONSTRAINT` which then led to me not putting the column name after `FOREIGN KEY`.  Is that correct, or am I stil not getting it?

Comment: @ Adam Halegua: you missed comma and column name after `FOREIGN KEY`. You could do it this way as well : `.... empname VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(empname) REFERENCES EMPADDRESS(empname),...`

Comment: @a1ex07 Awesome, thank you for taking the time to answer in both the normal and newbie version.  I really appreciate it :).

Comment: @ Adam Halegua: Np. One more thing worth mentioning: you normally should have an index on detail column of foreign key relation : `CREATE INDEX IDX_EMPHIREINFO_empname ON EMPHIREINFO(empname)`.

Comment: @a1ex07 Okay I haven't dealt with `indexes` yet which is why I left it out.  I'll look into that and start getting into the habit of using them, thanks again.